# centering a div containing left aligned text + another div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to:

- center a container div which contains 2 inline elements: Another div, and a title.
- The title can be any length.
- The elements must be next to each other.
- The text must be left aligned.
- The div must be vertically aligned to the center of text.

This is the aim:

[image: intention]

This is what I have so far.

HTML

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <h2>This is my title</h2>
  </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis ipsum reprehenderit ipsam hic adipisci ex obcaecati asperiores ab rerum, incidunt eius eligendi ea, odit, maiores fugit cumque modi, facere laudantium.</p>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <h2>This is another title. It could be any length. Any length at all.</h2>
  </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis ipsum reprehenderit ipsam hic adipisci ex obcaecati asperiores ab rerum, incidunt eius eligendi ea, odit, maiores fugit cumque modi, facere laudantium.</p>
</div>
```

CSS
    .container{
      width: 80%;
      height: auto;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: rgba(150,100,200,0.8);
      text-align: center;
      padding: 1em;
      p{
        text-align: left;
      }
    }

```
.box{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3em; 
  height: 3em;
  background-color: lightblue;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

h2{
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 4em);
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
}
```

And here it is in a [codepen](http://codepen.io/sanjaypoyzer/pen/KGCsy?editors=010)

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution with `display: table`.

**Edit** - Improved

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/pTcp4/2/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="heading">
        <div class="box">
            <div></div>
        </div>
         <h2>This is my title</h2>    
    </div>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.box {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.box div {
    width: 3em;
    height: 3em;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
h2 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 400px;
}
.heading {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Well ideally it would be centered, but is at the top like seems fine. Would it even be possible to center it?

Comment: @misterManSam That only centers on max-width. Not smaller. Otherwise it's pretty great.

Comment: Good point. @sanjaypoyzer [Here is your final solution that fixes everything nicely](http://jsfiddle.net/pTcp4/2/) :D

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pfbvH?editors=110

I created a class "title-box" and made the square and h2 inside table cells. The light blue square scales with the height of the header:

```
 .title-box {
   background-color: rgba(150,100,200,0.8);
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 1em;
   display: table;
 }

 .box{
   width: 3em; 
   height: 3em;
   background-color: lightblue;
   display: table-cell;
 }

 h2{
   margin: 0 auto;
   text-align: left;
   display: table-cell;
   padding: 10px;
 }
```